# Installing packages - Gviz, rtracklayer and trackViewer, in R

Tags: r, visualization, bioconductor, install.packages, genetic

I am trying to install the trackViewer package in R, following the instructions on the Bioconductor websites  https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/trackViewer/inst/doc/trackViewer.html.
https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/trackViewer.html

Every time I run the code

```
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("trackViewer")

if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("Gviz")
```

I get this error

```
'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories, see '?repositories' for details

replacement repositories:
    CRAN: https://cran.rstudio.com/

Bioconductor version 3.15 (BiocManager 1.30.18), R 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Warning message:
package(s) not installed when version(s) same as current; use `force = TRUE` to re-install: 'Gviz'
```

I'm not sure how to circumvent this. I am ultimately looking to create a lollipop plot to showcase mutations in a gene of interest with annotations.

I would appreciate any help with this.

Session info:

```
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.0.1

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[9] base     

other attached packages:
[1] Rcpp_1.0.9           GenomicRanges_1.48.0 GenomeInfoDb_1.32.3  IRanges_2.30.0      
[5] S4Vectors_0.34.0     BiocGenerics_0.42.0  BiocManager_1.30.18 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] MatrixGenerics_1.8.1        Biobase_2.56.0              httr_1.4.3                 
 [4] bit64_4.0.5                 assertthat_0.2.1            BiocFileCache_2.4.0        
 [7] blob_1.2.3                  BSgenome_1.64.0             GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.8     
[10] Rsamtools_2.12.0            yaml_2.3.5                  progress_1.2.2             
[13] pillar_1.8.0                RSQLite_2.2.16              lattice_0.20-45            
[16] glue_1.6.2                  digest_0.6.29               RColorBrewer_1.1-3         
[19] XVector_0.36.0              colorspace_2.0-3            htmltools_0.5.3            
[22] Matrix_1.4-1                XML_3.99-0.10               pkgconfig_2.0.3            
[25] biomaRt_2.52.0              zlibbioc_1.42.0             purrr_0.3.4                
[28] scales_1.2.0                BiocParallel_1.30.3         tibble_3.1.8               
[31] KEGGREST_1.36.3             generics_0.1.3              ellipsis_0.3.2             
[34] cachem_1.0.6                SummarizedExperiment_1.26.1 GenomicFeatures_1.48.3     
[37] cli_3.3.0                   magrittr_2.0.3              crayon_1.5.1               
[40] memoise_2.0.1               fansi_1.0.3                 xml2_1.3.3                 
[43] tools_4.2.1                 prettyunits_1.1.1           hms_1.1.1                  
[46] BiocIO_1.6.0                lifecycle_1.0.1             matrixStats_0.62.0         
[49] stringr_1.4.0               munsell_0.5.0               DelayedArray_0.22.0        
[52] AnnotationDbi_1.58.0        Biostrings_2.64.0           compiler_4.2.1             
[55] rlang_1.0.4                 RCurl_1.98-1.8              rstudioapi_0.13            
[58] rjson_0.2.21                rappdirs_0.3.3              htmlwidgets_1.5.4          
[61] bitops_1.0-7                restfulr_0.0.15             codetools_0.2-18           
[64] DBI_1.1.3                   curl_4.3.2                  R6_2.5.1                   
[67] GenomicAlignments_1.32.1    dplyr_1.0.9                 rtracklayer_1.56.1         
[70] fastmap_1.1.0               bit_4.0.4                   utf8_1.2.2                 
[73] filelock_1.0.2              stringi_1.7.8               parallel_4.2.1             
[76] vctrs_0.4.1                 png_0.1-7                   dbplyr_2.2.1               
[79] tidyselect_1.1.2
```

Comment: The warning message (and not error message) is telling you the package is already installed with latest version, so `library(Gviz)` should work

Comment: That is what I thought, but I get this error message "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Gviz’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘Hmisc’"

Comment: Then you need to install `Hmisc` as indicated by the error message

Comment: I tried both install.package("Hmisc") and library(Hmisc) and got the error that the package does not exist when I tried to load it.

Comment: You need to run `install.packages("Hmisc")`and not install.package("Hmisc")

Comment: Apologies about the typo in my comment, I double checked my code and I did run  install.packages("Hmisc") and was given options. I have tried saying yes/no on installation - I have now tried this multiple times, and every time it gives me an error and then library(Hmisc) says no package exists.

Comment: We need to know the complete error message you have

Comment: "Error in library(Hmisc) : there is no package called ‘Hmisc’"

Comment: After `install.packages("Hmisc")`

Comment: After library(Hmisc)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247337/discussion-between-basti-and-ar1229).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here warning message suggests that latest version of the package is already installed and if you want to reinstall the package then use `force=TRUE` like this :

`BiocManager::install("Gviz", force = TRUE)`